# understanding the For Each Loop

Tags: loops, vbscript, wmi

I'm new to scripting and programming.

In the following and similar scripts, I noticed that there exists a 'objOperatingSystem'
that is referred to in the 'For Each' loop. 
I understand that 'colSettings' is a variable that contains the WMI collection, but where does the 'objOperatingSystem' come from ?

Pls help. Thanks!!!

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings 
    Wscript.Echo "Available Physical Memory: " & _
        objOperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory
Next
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objOperatingSystem` is a variable. `For Each` declared it. Basically, for every item in `colSettings` a variable named `objOperatingSystem` will be set to the current item, and the body of the for loop executed.

Comment: Its vbscript. Ah I see! so basically it could have been any other word, so long as you type something after 'For Each' (ie. For Each yabadaba) The 'yabadaba' is basically a declared variable that will store an element of the array collection.

Comment: To add some flavour `WMI` is being used to check how much free memory is available in each operating system installed on the local pc (`strComputer = "."`)

Answer (score 0):

It's vb script. And it's looking into the operating system object thru WMI to see available memory. it's part on the winmgmts (windows management) object. Use a neat tool called WMI creator and surf all the cool wmi's on your computer. It's is just a variable created to hold the object it's looking for in WMI and then iterates thru it "for each" time.